# How to add string word to Kstream<String, String>?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I tried to add word "cat" to "input" in many ways but didn't work. What should I do to merge word "cat" in "input"

```
static void createWordCountStream(final StreamsBuilder builder) {

        final KStream<String, String> input = builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC);
        Sting word = "cat";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka Streams cannot produce to a topic without consuming from another

If you simply want to "add a string to a topic", you'd use a plain Producer class, or CLI tool, e.g.

```
echo "cat" > kcat -P -b localhost:9092 -t input-topic
```